# adding a ForeignKey constraint to an existing SQLAlchemy table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an existing table

```
class Table1(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    primary_category_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Table1 %r>' % (self.id)
```

which is populated already. Now I want to add a new Table

```
class Query_Category(db.Model):

    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_string = db.Column(db.String(1000))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Query_Category %r>' % (self.category_id)
```

And the category_id of the old table Table1, now should be a Foreign key of the new Table. I am using flask-migrate to add the Query_Category Table and that works fine, but how do I add the Foreign key constraint?
I tried to just add it as

```
primary_category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('query_category.category_id'))
```

and run flask-migrate, but that leads to the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'Table1.primary_category_id' could not find table 'query_category' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'category_id'
```

How do I add a Foreign key constraint to an existing Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add a `__tablename__` field to your model

```
class Query_Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'query_category'
```

Comment: yes that seem to do it... can you explain why? I do not specify the table name in all other cases and the relationships don't seem to have a problem? thanks anyway

Comment: I can't explain this, that was my first thought when i saw  error `could not find table 'query_category' `

Comment: I'd guess that ```db.Model``` adds a default __tablename__ to your classes and that the default table name for the ```Query_Category``` was not 'query_category'